# Why ajax parsing will not allow Spring MVC controller to redirect jsp pages?

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have been using `ModelAndView` as the object type in my controller to handle method to do data binding with front-end html form.Such as this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postSth", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView postSomething(@RequestParam("name") String name){
       ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("displayPage");
       model.addObject("name", name);
       return model;
}
```

This method will allow me to bind the `name` and I can display the `name` to the `displayPage.jsp` after the `POST` method. `displayPage` is the `JSP` page name and by using the `InternalResourceViewResolver` from Spring framework.

Lately I have been using jQuery `ajax` function to pass the data to my controller, and I am working on method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(headers = "Content-Type=application/json", value = "/postSth", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public ModelAndView postSomething(@RequestBody String name){
       ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("displayPage");
       model.addObject("name", name);
       return model;
}
```

I noticed I can successfully grabbing the `JSON` string with this controller, but this method will not redirect my webpage to the `displayPage` and the data binding with `.addObject` no longer work.

Why it does not work? How do I change it to still allow me to direct to the `displayPage.jsp`?  I understand I can do the redirect with javascript at front-end, but it is not what I want to do.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you're making the request with ajax, that ajax request's response will contain the html rendered by the `displayPage`.

Comment: What do you mean this method does not work? Is the output something other than the contents of `displayPage`? Are you getting an error response? Are you getting some other kind of response?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The `displayPage` is the `jsp` page that I am trying to redirect to after the `POST`, in another words when doing with `ajax` it stops the redirect to the `displayPage.jsp` that normally works without ajax.

Comment: You keep using the term _redirect_ but that term means an entirely different thing. What you mean is a Servlet `RequestDispatcher` **forward** which simply renders the JSP's HTML and writes it to the response. If you print the content of the response you receive from the request you make in ajax, you'll see the same thing.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think redirect was not the correct word and your are correct, and I understand I am getting the content of the response. What I was wondering was why the `RequestDispatcher` does not render the `displayPage.jsp` anymore when doing the ajax?

Comment: Maybe you've misunderstand what ajax requests are. Read the first paragraph of the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So the wiki says "without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page", so that is the reason?

Comment: Yes, indeed. The ajax request/response is separate from the browser's UI request/response handling. (Though it can interact with it.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The work I am doing is passing the ajax data to the controller so that I can call database, and display the database respond information to another jsp page based on the respond. If ajax will not invoke the rendering the `jsp`, what should i do so that I can achieve this with ajax?

Comment: No. You misunderstand. Ajax is just a methodology. A request is sent and a response is generated. Spring generates that response by having the servlet container render the JSP. That content is sent in the HTTP response. However, the browser does not display that content. That's the only difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your requirement as you trigger an ajax call but instead of loading the output of data to current jsp you need to populate it in new jsp.

I have had the similar requirement, I used jquery load() to implement it. It worked fine in my case. Basically its like a 3 step process;

1. Trigger Ajax call to the controller to get the required data to be loaded on new jsp.
2. use load() once required data is available to load the new jsp in current page.(you can use some div to load it, if you want to completely replace current page then empty the contents of current page and laod with new jsp)
3. Write javascript/jquery codes to manipulate the dom in new JSP which we rendered on previous step.

Below is the snippet of how it can be done.

```
@RequestMapping(headers = "Content-Type=application/json", value = "/postSth", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public String postSomething(@RequestBody String name){

       return model;
}

<div id='currentContent'>
        <!--Existing content -->
</div>
var ajaxResult = '';
$.ajax({
    type : POST,
    url: "postSth",
    async:false}).then(function(data){
        //DIV ID here would be the ID which you need to have in your page to append the HTML content.
        //if you want to completely reload the page then use the id where your current contents are displayed
        //Inside your somenewjsp.jsp you can write your jquery codes to access the variable ajaxResult on document ready
        ajaxResult = data;
        $('#currentContent').load('/somenewjsp.jsp');
    });
});
```

Please share your results on this approach.